# Custom control in DataGridView cell

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have a custom control in a DataGridView cell.  Its a combobox that contains checkbox items (CheckBoxComboBox).  Here's the issue :
1. Enter one of the CheckBoxComboBoxes and select off some checkbox items.  The Text of the CheckboxComboBox is a csv string of the checked items.
2. Click a different CheckboxComboBox cell that is emtpy (no checked items)

Result : The text of the new cell contains the text of the old cell.  If I click a CheckBoxComboBox cell, then a non-CheckBoxComboBox cell and then a CheckBoxComboBox cell, it works correctly.

I have read and implemented the custom DataGridViewCell based on this document :
[How to: Host Controls in Windows Forms DataGridView Cells](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx?PHPSESSID=o1fb21liejulfgrptbmi9dec92)

When I debug through my custom DataGridViewEditingControl, it appears that the EditingControl.Tag isn't updated.

So I am assuming that I have an issue with the EditingControl is being reused.

Things I have tried :

**1. Override DataGridViewCell.Clone()**

```
    public override object Clone()
    {
        DataGridViewCheckBoxComboBoxCell checkBoxComboBoxCell = base.Clone() as DataGridViewCheckBoxComboBoxCell;
        if (checkBoxComboBoxCell != null)
        {
            checkBoxComboBoxCell.Tag = this.Tag;
            checkBoxComboBoxCell.Values = this.Values;


        }
        return checkBoxComboBoxCell; 
    }
```

**2.  Override DataGridViewCell.DetachEditingControl()**

```
public override void DetachEditingControl()
    {
        DataGridView dataGridView = this.DataGridView;

        if (dataGridView == null || dataGridView.EditingControl == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Cell is detached or its grid has no editing control.");
        }

        DataGridViewCheckBoxComboBoxCellEditingControl ctl = DataGridView.EditingControl as DataGridViewCheckBoxComboBoxCellEditingControl;
        if (ctl != null)
        {
            //Just trying different things
            ctl.EditingControlFormattedValue = String.Empty;
            ctl.Text = string.Empty;
            ctl.Tag = null;
            ctl.Items.Clear();
        }

        base.DetachEditingControl();
    }
```

Any idea how to resolve this issue ?  Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

Here is the DataGridViewCheckBoxComboBoxColumn class

```
class DataGridViewCheckBoxComboBoxColumn : DataGridViewColumn
{
     public override object Clone()
    {
        DataGridViewCheckBoxComboBoxColumn that = (DataGridViewCheckBoxComboBoxColumn)base.Clone();

        return that;
    }

    private DataGridViewCheckBoxComboBoxCell _cell = null;
    public DataGridViewCheckBoxComboBoxColumn()
    {
        _cell = new DataGridViewCheckBoxComboBoxCell();
        base.CellTemplate = _cell;
    }

    public override DataGridViewCell CellTemplate
    {
        get
        {
            return base.CellTemplate;
        }
        set
        {
            // Ensure that the cell used for the template is a DateCell.
            if (value != null &&
                !value.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(DataGridViewCheckBoxComboBoxCell)))
            {
                throw new InvalidCastException("Must be a DataGridViewCheckBoxComboBoxColumn");
            }
            base.CellTemplate = value;
        }
    }

    public string Values
    {
        set
        {
            _cell.Tag = value;
            this.Tag = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return _cell.Tag.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**
My DataGridViewCheckBoxComboBoxCell overrides Paint().  When I put a breakpoint on this method, it gets called twice when I click the cell. The first time its called, the formattedValue is empty.  However, the second time, the formattedValue contains the incorrect string of the previous checkboxcombobox cell.

```
protected override void Paint(Graphics graphics, Rectangle clipBounds, Rectangle cellBounds, int rowIndex,
                                  DataGridViewElementStates cellState, object value, object formattedValue,
                                  string errorText, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle,
                                  DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle,
                                  DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
    {}
```

Why does it get called twice and why on the second call does it contain the wrong formatted value for the correct cell?

Comment: What's the code look like when you add your DataGridViewCheckBoxComboBoxCell(s) to the DataGridView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. The issue was that in the DetachEditingControl() I needed to clear the CheckBoxItems.

```
public override void DetachEditingControl()
    {
        DataGridView dataGridView = this.DataGridView;

        if (dataGridView == null || dataGridView.EditingControl == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Cell is detached or its grid has no editing control.");
        }

        DataGridViewCheckBoxComboBoxCellEditingControl ctl = DataGridView.EditingControl as DataGridViewCheckBoxComboBoxCellEditingControl;
        if (ctl != null)
        {
            ctl.CheckBoxItems.Clear();  //Forgot to do this.
            ctl.EditingControlFormattedValue = String.Empty;
        }

        base.DetachEditingControl();
    }
```

Comment: Hey Web I'm having similar issues. I've created a custom comboBox that allows the user to add items to my comobox and remove items by clicking on an image next to item. I have a column with different cellTypes (dataGridViewTextBoxCell, dataGridViewButtonCell, etc) and my custom comboBox. If i have more than 1 custom comboBox they all seem to be using the same editingControl data instead of their own items and if I select another type of control all my comboBoxes lose their items/data. Can I take a look at an example of how you implemented your's?